# Add login condition to laravel ui auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-ui

I am using laravel ui auth package for my login. But i want to add new condition for the user to login besides email and password which is isBanned boolean. However, i dont know where and files for me to edit to add the new condition.

Answer (score 7):

You should have a Controller in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` named `LoginController`. This Controller uses a trait `AuthenticatesUsers`. What you want to do is adjust the credentials passed to `attempt` that is happening. This can be done by overriding the `credentials` method on `LoginController`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password') + [
        'isBanned' => false
    ];
}
```

This is adding `isBanned` to the credentials which are all "where" conditions on a query to find the user (except for the 'password' field).

### UPDATE:

If you want to be able to know if the user had bad credentials or if they are banned then you don't need to override the `credentials` method and you can just override the `attemptLogin` method and the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method on `LoginController`:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attemptWhen(
        $this->credentials($request),
        fn ($user) => ! $user->isBanned,
        $request->filled('remember')
    )
}


protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [
            $user && $this->guard()->getProvider()->validateCredentials($user, $this->credentials($request))
                ? 'You are banned'
                : trans('auth.failed')
        ]
    ]);
}
```

We are not adjusting the credentials so we are letting the User Provider get the user based on their credentials (username/email and password). The call to `attemptWhen` lets us add a callback condition to see if we want to log them in after we have retrieved the user by their credentials and validated them. We create a callback that checks if the user is banned. In the `sendFailedLoginResponse` we are checking to see if the guard has a `lastAttempted` set (did the User Provider retrieve a user based on credentials). If it does have a User and the credentials are valid then they must be banned otherwise they would have been logged in. All other cases we return the auth failed message.

Comment: this works! thank you so much. but now i have a problem which is i dont know where to edit the error message as the default error message is "the credentials didnt match". I want to send different error message is the user is banned

Comment: the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method returns the error message but even from the `login` method itself currently you woudln't know why the login failed (bad credentials or banned) you would have to rewrite part of the login process to be able to determine that

Comment: in auth.php there is code there is authentication error message but the only one is working is failed because even is the password is incorrectly input by the user, the error message specifically for the password is not displayed.

Comment: right because you don't do that ... you don't want to give a malicious person information like that ... if they know a username is good but a password is bad then they can keep trying that username with different passwords ... if you keep them in the dark they don't know what part of the credentials failing (that is done on purpose) ... also if you only say the password is wrong now I know that that user exists in the system (so you have leaked information)

Comment: if you want to know that information you will be rewriting part of the login process of the `LoginController` and what the guard would be doing `SessionGuard` (which is what attempts to do the login by querying for the user with the credentials and doing the hash check on the password)

Comment: i understand now the security part, thank you.

Comment: if you just want to be able to tell them if they are banned, you could do this with overriding 2 methods on `LoginController` and macroing a new `attempt` like method to the `SessionGuard` ... adding the condition to the credentials is what makes this a lil trickier, otherwise you could attempt to log them in without that condition and after it finds the user check if they are banned, but that is a lil dirtier but might be the easier option

Comment: @TurtleDeveloper updated with a way for you to distinguish if a user was banned, no longer overriding the credentials but overriding 2 methods on `LoginController`

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Ya'll wasting your time overriding the `AuthenticatesUsers` when you can just create a new `Middleware` that will check if the `user` is *banned* or *not*.